# Any way to get current userId from Spring Security in a repository?

Tags: hibernate, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Spring Data repository with multiple native queries, all of which need to be filtered by the currently logged user (as in, "and where user_id = ?" should be included in every query). Is there a way to access the userId from Spring Security from the repo and use it in a query? I can get userId in the controller and pass it to the repo as a method parameter, but this gets quite repetitive when multiple methods are involved.
Sample query from the repo below:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT project_id) FROM reports r WHERE r.month = ?1 AND r.year = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    int getTotalProjectsByMonth(int month, int year);
```

Comment: Yes. You can use  Spring expression language in the query to get the principal from the SecurityContext. See here as a startng point: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-security

Comment: Interesting! That's a good pointer, thank you, but as I understand there is no way to get userId from Spring Security directly, I would probably need custom UserDetailsService with a method that pulls userId from the database?

Comment: Not sure I follow, If the principal in the security context has a method getId or whatever then reference it in your query principal?.id or whatever.

Comment: It doesn't have any method for getting the Id, that's why I'm asking about a custom service.

Comment: What exactly do you have in the security context?

Answer (score -1):

You can try with

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Comment: That's going to work in a class, but not in a repo which is an interface. Getting user's details in a class isn't the problem, getting them in the repo is.

Comment: Is your import correct ?
You should use
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
It's in the spring-security-core library